# C# How to cancel previous button click event handlers in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF application that fetches data from a database and displays information in the form a table. There is a refresh button that can be clicked and it updates the table. When the user clicks on the refresh button repeatedly the application hangs for a couple seconds.

I tried experimenting with `async` and `await` but it is still locking up.

**Before:**

```
public void Refresh_Handler(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Refresh(); //asynchronous method that has several nested awaits
    ...
}
```

**After:**

```
var task = Task.Run(() =>
{
    this.Refresh();
});

async void runTask()
{
    this.cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    try
    {
        await task();
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException ex)
    {
         Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(OperationCanceledException)} thrown with message: {ex.Message}");
    }
    finally
    {
        this.cts = null;
    }
}

if (this.cts == null)
{
    runTask();
}
else
{
    this.cts.Cancel();
    runTask();
}
```

> **How can I cancel previous/pending refresh clicks and make the UI responsive?** Currently it is stacking the requests and locking the application when the refresh button is pressed repeatedly. I would like it to kick off a brand new request on the final button click so that the app doesn't *hang*.

Comment: I would disable the button until the refresh is finished so it cannot be clicked repeatedly.

Comment: Is cancelling previous request really necessary? You could just not fire a new request if another request is already in progress. You could accomplish this, as already suggested, by disabling the button, or by creating a flag indicating if data is loading and checking it before firing a new request.

Comment: Is `Refresh` really cancellable? How is it implemented? You can't cancel an API that doesn't supports cancellation.

Comment: @AdamŠtafa The `Refresh` method is `async void` so I am having difficulties 'awaiting' it. The way our system works is that `Refresh` is called in a setter so I can't turn it into a task.. that's the dilemma I am in right now.

Comment: What I will have to end up doing is create a new method `async Task` RefreshAsync and use that instead.